# Parse Cloud Job giving me error 159

Tags: parse-platform

I'm running a scheduled job on parse.com and the logs are telling me that I have error: 159.. Result: Existence checking query failed. Error: 159 temporary error.

Trying to figure out how to resolve this, has anyone had any luck?

Comment: "The error code 159 indicates that your app has been throttled by us. This itself is not a bug." https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/200704853640553/


Having the same problem. Any luck with it since you asked the question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - yeah, it had to do with me not migrating my data.  Once i started the migration process, it started working again.